# sudo apt-add-repository multiverse gives error Connection refused

Tags: debian, linux-mint, apt, repository

I am trying to add i386 sources to 64bit Linux Mint as per the [instructions for SteamCMD](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/SteamCMD#Linux). However I get the following error:

```
user@mintpc:/home/steam/games/steamapps$ sudo apt-add-repository multiverse
No protocol specified
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
No protocol specified
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
```

I have no idea what that means and there seem to be no answers on the internet.

Answer (score 0):

I unfortunately don't have any answer for you, but I will add that I'm encountering the same problem while trying to add the deadsnake repo for python 3.10 on my Linux Mint box:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
Cannot add PPA: '"Failed to download the PPA: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='launchpad.net', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/1.0/~deadsnakes/+archive/ppa (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f9d3e72a340>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable'))."'.
```

I literally just ran a full system update that downloaded and installed dozens of packages, and if I run...

`sudo nping --tcp -p 443 ppa.launchpad.net`

...I get a response back, so I'm at a bit of a loss to explain what's happening.

Comment: Okay... best I can suggest is to try it again, and again, because with no apparent explanation, one time it gave the same "Unable to init server:..." but then suddenly loaded the ppa info.  Weird.